Ubuntu 24.04 (Nomble Numbat) hangs on installation
I've been trying to install the new Ubuntu 24.04 (Nomble Numbat) on a PC that's been running 22.04 for a while.  Observations:

Upon boot from the USB stick it errors out quickly (IIRC "Oh no something went wrong!" but I don't remember exactly).

It seems the new installer is unhappy with something about my disk partitioning (tri-boot: Windows, Debian, and Ubuntu, with the later two sharing LUKS and LVM volumes).  If I unlock the LUKS partitions and restart the installer, I get the first screen to select my language, click "Next", and it just spins.

After a bunch of trial-and-error I discovered if I boot a fresh installer and quickly kill it (presumably before it caches some data that contributes to the error), then unlock the LUKS partitions, the installer makes it further but still ultimately hangs.  By poking around I found subiquity-server-info.log, which contains:


2024-04-27 00:59:23,292 INFO subiquity:201 Starting Subiquity server revision 171 of snap /snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171 of version 0+git.2d119e1b3
2024-04-27 00:59:23,292 INFO subiquity:205 Arguments passed: ['/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/bin/subiquity/subiquity/cmd/server.py', '--use-os-prober', '--storage-version=2', '--postinst-hooks-dir=/snap/ubuntu-desktop-bootstrap/171/etc/subiquity/postinst.d']
2024-04-27 00:59:25,292 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,295 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/apply_autoinstall_config: SUCCESS: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,559 ERROR root:38 finish: subiquity/Refresh/check_for_update: FAIL: cancelled
2024-04-27 00:59:25,598 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,599 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "nonreportable_erro...
2024-04-27 00:59:25,602 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,602 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/client_variant_POST: SUCCESS: 200 null
2024-04-27 00:59:25,603 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,603 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "nonreportable_erro...
2024-04-27 00:59:25,604 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/mark_configured_POST: 
2024-04-27 00:59:25,605 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/mark_configured_POST: SUCCESS: 200 null
2024-04-27 00:59:25,636 ERROR probert.multipath:38 Failed to run cmd: ['multipathd', 'show', 'maps', 'raw', 'format', '%w,%d,%N']
2024-04-27 00:59:25,636 ERROR probert.multipath:38 Failed to run cmd: ['multipathd', 'show', 'paths', 'raw', 'format', '%d,%z,%m,%N,%n,%R,%r,%a']
2024-04-27 00:59:26,190 INFO probert.lvm:120 b'  9 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active\n'
2024-04-27 00:59:26,266 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,266 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,266 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,267 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,267 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,267 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,268 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,268 ERROR probert.lvm:225 Found duplicate volume group: ubuntu-vg
2024-04-27 00:59:26,364 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:26,364 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "nonreportable_erro...
2024-04-27 00:59:26,365 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:26,365 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: SUCCESS: 200 {"state": "WAITING", "confirming_tty": "", "error": null, "nonreportable_erro...
2024-04-27 00:59:26,366 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/status_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:26,366 INFO root:38 start: subiquity/Meta/interactive_sections_GET: 
2024-04-27 00:59:26,366 INFO root:38 finish: subiquity/Meta/interactive_sections_GET: SUCCESS: 200 null

Any suggestions about how to debug this further and/or work around?  I was going to install it over an existing volume, anyway (e.g., wipe my Debian volume), so if I could, for example, run the installer from my 22.04 volume that would at least speed my debugging cycles and make it easier to get logs and screenshots from the installer into bug reports.

I have a similar problem with a Dell XPS 13 and luks encryption. In my case it boots fine and starts the installer, but then hangs somewhere during installation. I've done this several times and where it hangs seems to change. By hangs, I really mean that after I click next, the wait cursor spins for 5 to 10 minutes until I kill it.

Sometimes I can advance progress by clicking back and next again. Eventually this fails and I get to a page that says something went wrong. Clicking show log shows an empty window.

what works for me is just disable the internet (WIFI) during the setup phase and everything is fine so seems like there is a possible timeout or recurring issue in these repose for some regions, may be disabling the internet will help to complete setup

I did get further by disabling Wi-Fi, but only to the point where the installer says copying files and subiquity log says configuring apt. It stayed in that state for about 6 hours before I stopped it.

I had the same problem and in the end it was my SSD that still contained partitions from my previous Windows 10 installation on this disk.
Instead of having the installer partition the SSD I decided to remove all the partitions by formatting the SSD without any partition using the "Disks" tool.

select the disk
click on the "Drive options" button (3 dots) on the right
select "Format disk..."
select "No partitioning (empty)" under "Partitioning"
select "No partitioning (empty)"

Then I restarted the installation,let Ubuntu manage the partitioning for me , selected the SSD disk and now the installation was successful!

Sorry, none of the suggestions help, including the "no internet" one.  I do find the non-determinism concerning since I had the same observation as @reece.  The reformatting suggestion would almost certainly work, but defeats the purpose as I've got 10TB of data I was trying to preserve.  Instead I just used normal mechanisms to upgrade to 23.10 and then to 24.04 and it "worked"... except 24.04 fails to unlock one of the PVs in the VG on boot and drops me into initramfs.  sigh

At this moment I would advise to not upgrade to 24 as it does not seem stable. Although I managed to install v24 I received several “crash reports” on a daily basis. The OS continued working but I didn’t feel confident using it. Stick to v23 for now. In my case installed Linux Mint which works flawlessly, except for unstable bluetooth support which is another topic. ☺️ PS. If possible you could try to install Ubuntu 24 on a secondary HDD/SSD in order to safeguard your existing v23. This way you try and experiment until v24 is stable enough and then upgrade your v23.

Try safe graphics mode. I had the same problem and it worked!

All that does is stop the video driver from loading. Not the issue the OP describes.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
